# Wordpress else statement on custom query

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a custom query and i want to know how i can add an if statement, so that if there is no posts for this query, a simple message gets displayed.

My query:

```
    <ul class="posts">
        <?php if ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) while ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) : $spQuery->the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'themename-bw-image' ); ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
```

I was trying this:

```
        <ul class="posts">
            <?php if ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) while ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) : $spQuery->the_post(); ?>

            <li><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'themename-bw-image' ); ?></li>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        </ul>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No Posts Currently Added.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But i get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE`

Probably doing something stupidly wrong here, but i thought this was a valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add curly braces  (or put a colon after the : if ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) instead of curly braces)

```
   <ul class="posts">
        <?php if ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) { while ( $spQuery->have_posts() ) : $spQuery->the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'themename-bw-image' ); ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </ul>

    <?php } else {  ?>
        <p>No Posts Currently Added.</p>
    <?php } ?>
```